# Is there a service that would notify me whenever a hotel room becomes available for booking in a given city?

Tags: bookings, hotels, accommodation, hostels, booking.com

I want to travel to a city (Arnhem, NL) at time when all hotels and hostels, which meet my standards, are booked. I wonder if there is some service which can notify me when something convenient becomes available (for example, if somebody canceled the booking).

Is there any service which can do that? Didn't find anything on Booking.com, maybe some other website can.

Comment: I don't know of any services that offer that, but you may want to contact some hostels/hotels directly.  Some hostels/hotels have beds that they don't make available on the online booking sites.

Comment: Have you considered booking (maybe with free cancelation) in a nearby city? Dutch trains run a commuter service and being in the next city is like being in a different part of a big city like London or NYC. Nijmegen and Utrecht come to mind but there are more options.

Comment: In addition to what @Willeke says, you can even consider hotels across the border in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [HotelRoomAlerts.com](http://www.hotelroomalerts.com/).

Alternatively, you can contact the hotel directly and ask them to place a reservation that will become effective if (or as soon as) another guest cancels their stay.